# Google Local Home SDK UDP commands to BrighSign player

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-home

For a research, I want to try controlling a BrightSign player with a Google Nest Hub.
The BrightSign player support UDP commands with ASCII/HEX on default the receiving port 5000.

Because the player is not a smart device, can I use the Google Local Home SDK, to send UDP commands with the HEX only to non-smart devices?

If so, does someone have an example of TypeScript of JavaScript how to set this up?

I'm new to both languages and just want to implement this simple feature.

Thanks.

I already tried this tutorial: https://developers.home.google.com/local-home/overview.

But I did not got it to work with my device.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the Google Local Home SDK to send UDP commands with the HEX only to non-smart devices. The Local Home SDK is not just limited to sending intents and receiving responses over a local fulfillment path. The device should have either Bluetooth or WiFi capability to function properly with the local home SDK.

As your BrighSign player is not a smart device it won’t be able to successfully complete the Local Home SDK setup and intent flow mechanism. More information in this regard can be found [here](https://developers.home.google.com/local-home/overview).